# Characters in DB displaying strangely

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, numbers, special-characters

I'm creating a trivia iPhone app. I've written 1,000 questions or so in the mac app Numbers. The problem I'm having is that when I export the document to a CSV then open it in mySQL lite and save it as a database for the app, things like apostrophes turn out strangely for example "there's" would turn out as thereás instead. Is there any easy way to correct this issue?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Are you saving the text in <html> tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are generating the CSV file from a MS doc or excel file

where

if i write "`There’s`" in MS Doc(look the apstrophe character)

but if i write same text in a simple text file "`There's`" (look the changed apstrophe character)

That is why the text is displaying as thereás due to character encoding problem.

So you have to change the (`’`)character in to (`'`) to display it correctly.

Comment: @edhog,how about a thumb up to this answer